# How to determinate "ISO 8601 month part" of datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting, iso8601

In my query i need to get month part of some date using "ISO 8601"-rules. To get ISO-week there is "ISO_WEEK" can be passed as first parameter to [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function. But what is for month?

ISO month is not same as calendar months...

For example, we have date "28 December 2010". Calendar month and year says that it's "12-th month of 2010", but by ISO it's a "1-th month of 2011", because ISO-month starts at first sunday(i.e. "26 December 2010") before 1-th day of month.

So how to determine ISO-month in SQL-server?

Comment: There is no DATEPART parameter for ISO-month because ISO-month doesn't appear to be a standard thing. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) So you need a formula based on your definition of "ISO-month."

Comment: Never heard about ISO months. Can you please give a source for the definition?

Comment: It's defined as "ISO Month and Week" in documents of "Gesellschaft für Konsumforschung"(GFK-group) market research company. They send us tables with dates like this as input for business analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your definition of ISO-month you should be able to compare how close you are to the end of the month to the day of the week and know if your ISO month matches the Gregorian month or not.

```
DECLARE @date TABLE (d DATE, expected INT)
INSERT INTO @date VALUES 
 ('2014-03-23',3)
 ,('2014-03-24',3)
 ,('2014-03-25',3)
 ,('2014-03-26',3)
 ,('2014-03-27',3)
 ,('2014-03-28',3)
 ,('2014-03-29',3)
 ,('2014-03-30',4)
 ,('2014-03-31',4)
 ,('2014-04-01',4)
 ,('2010-12-28',1)

SET DATEFIRST 7 --sunday/default us

SELECT DATEPART(DAY,EOMONTH(d)) EndOfMonth
      ,DATEPART(DAY,d) DayOfMonth
      ,DATEPART(d,EOMONTH ( d)) - DATEPART(D,d) [EoM-DoM]
      ,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,d) DayOfWeek
      --here's the real work
      ,CASE WHEN 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY,d) > DATEPART(d,EOMONTH ( d)) - DATEPART(D,d)
            THEN DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(m,1,d))
            ELSE DATEPART(MONTH,d)
       END [iso-month]
      ,expected          
  FROM @date
```